# Is Direct2D supposed to respect WS_CLIPCHILDREN?

Tags: windows, winapi, direct2d

My main window has some child windows that contain movies managed by Media Foundation. The main window is drawn using Direct2D. I'm not doing any clipping when drawing the main window with Direct2D because I expect this to be done by `BeginPaint` in my `WM_PAINT`.

When my window is rather small, everything is drawn fine. However, when I maximize it to a 4096x2304px resolution, there is visible flicker and I can quickly see the stuff drawn by Direct2D beneath the Media Foundation child windows before Media Foundation draws its contents to them so it looks like Direct2D clipping doesn't really happen.

Is this true? Do I have to manually set up a Direct2D clipping region to prevent it from overdrawing the Media Foundation child windows or am I doing something wrong here? My main window has `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` set.

Comment: Devil hides in details. It ultimately depends how you code all that parts together (devices, swap chain, how/what do you draw with MF?, etc.). One thing for sure, this is definitely the kind of scenario that is covered by Direct Composition (win32) and the newer Windows.UI.Composition (winrt). It's meant for "composing" a scene (with DirectX techs), which seems to be what you're doing here. Otherwise, have you some reproducing project?

Comment: @SimonMourier: I haven't created a MVCE yet because there's obviously quite some code involved. I did try to use `PushAxisAlignedClip` and `PopAxisAlignedClip` , though, to see if it makes a difference if I manually set a clipping region but unfortunately, this doesn't help, which is somewhat confusing me. It still seems to draw beneath the Media Foundation child windows although I explicitly specified a clipping region using `PushAxisAlignedClip`. Very strange :/

Comment: Actually, drawing doesn't seem to be the culprit at all but `BeginDraw` and `EndDraw` are. I can remove *all* drawing code and it will still flicker. Just calling `BeginDraw` and `EndDraw` is enough to make it flicker.

Comment: Oops, sorry, this turned out to be a bug in my code. For some reason `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` didn't get set on window creation. I have fixed this and now everything is working fine. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Like I said, devil hides in details :-)